# I want to insert the record which is not already inserted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Timetable values ('E-465458',1,1,8,10,11) 
SELECT StaffID, ClassTimingId,WeekDayId,DepartmentId,ClassID,SectionID
FROM TimeTable
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM Timetable
          WHERE WeekDayId = 1 AND DepartmentId = 8  and ClassTiminng = 1  ) ;
```

I have table with name Timetable if `WeekdayID` is alredy 1 and `DepartmentId=8` and `ClassTiming=1` then dont insert the record it search all rows in table

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: And what is your problem you have? Maybe there is really just "NOT" missing.

Comment: its not working in Not EXISTS i tried that also

Comment: This task better fits to a MERGE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do both `VALUES` and `SELECT` at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO Timetable  
SELECT 'E-465458',1,1,8,10,11
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM Timetable
          WHERE WeekDayId = 1 AND DepartmentId = 8  and ClassTiminng = 1  ) ;
```

Or better switch to a MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO Timetable AS tgt 
USING VALUES ('E-465458',1,1,8,10,11) AS src (StaffID, ClassTimingId,WeekDayId,DepartmentId,ClassID,SectionID)
  ON tgt.WeekDayId     = src.WeekDayId
 AND tgt.DepartmentId  = src.DepartmentId
 AND tgt.ClassTimingId = src.ClassTimingId
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (src.StaffID, src.ClassTimingId,src.WeekDayId,src.DepartmentId,src.ClassID,src.SectionID)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Timetable
        WHERE WeekDayId = 1
            AND DepartmentId = 8
            AND ClassTiming = 1
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Timetable (StaffID, ClassTimingId, WeekDayId, DepartmentId, ClassID, SectionID)
    VALUES ('E-465458', 1, 1, 8, 10, 11)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with irshad, you can try this to optimize the query :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Timetable
                  WHERE WeekDayId = 1 AND DepartmentId = 8  and ClassTiming = 1 )
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Timetable (StaffID, ClassTimingId,WeekDayId,DepartmentId,ClassID,SectionID) VALUES ('E-465458',1,1,8,10,11) 
   END
```